# Python telnet not showing result

Tags: python, telnetlib

with python script I want to make some configuration on mikrotik routers, looks like script is right and no gives errors but ends without printing command outputs

```
import telnetlib
import time
dev_ip = "172.16.62.160"
user = "admin"
PASSWORD = ""
comm1 = "ip address print"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(dev_ip, timeout=1)
tn.read_until(b"Login: ")
tn.write(user.encode("ascii") + b'\n')
tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn.write(PASSWORD.encode("ascii") + b'\n')
tn.read_until(b">")
time.sleep(1)
tn.write(comm1.encode("ascii") + b"\r\n")
Showcmdoutput = tn.read_very_eager().decode('ascii')
print(Showcmdoutput)
tn.close()
print("DONE")
```

running on Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: If there is even the slightest delay before the router starts responding to the command you sent, `.read_very_eager()` is going to return an empty string - it doesn't wait for data to become available.  A short `sleep()` after the command might help, or changing to use `.read_until()` if there's some guaranteed string that will always appear  at the end of the command's results.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved after putting:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

before `Showcmdoutput = tn.read_very_eager().decode('ascii')`

```
tn.write(comm1.encode("ascii") + b"\r\n")
time.sleep(1)
Showcmdoutput = tn.read_very_eager().decode('ascii')
```